# svcutil not downloading full metadata

Tags: wcf, metadata, svcutil.exe

When I try to generate metadata using svcutil (svcutil.exe /t:metadata http://`localhost`/ABCService/Service.svc ), I dont get full/all metadata (input-output data contract) . However I can see all metadata (input-output data contract) when I do a "Add Service Reference" in Visual studio. Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try using Visual Studio's "add service reference"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was, it got automatically resolved after restarting the system